# SQL Query using Partition By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table name JobTitle

```
JobID LanaguageID
-----------------
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         2 
3         4
4         5
5         2
```

I am selecting all records from table except duplicate JobID's for which count > 1. I am selecting only one record/first row from the duplicate JobID's.
Now I am passing LanguageID as paramter to stored procedure and I want to select duplicate JobID for that languageID along with the other records Also.
If I have passed languageID as 1 then output should come as follows

```
JobID LanaguageID
-----------------
1         1
2         1
3         4
4         5
5         2
```

I have tried using following query.

```
with CTE_RN as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobTitle.JobID ORDER BY JobTitle.JobTitle) AS RN
    FROM JobTitle
    INNER JOIN JobTitle_Lang
        ON JobTitle.JobTitleID = JobTitle_Lang.JobTitleID
)
```

But I am unable to use WHERE clause in the above query.
Is any different approch should be followed. Or else how can i modify the query to get the desired output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
with CTE_RN as
(
    SELECT
        JobID, LanaguageID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobTitle.JobID ORDER BY JobTitle.JobTitle) AS RN
    FROM JobTitle
        INNER JOIN JobTitle_Lang ON JobTitle.JobTitleID = JobTitle_Lang.JobTitleID
)
select
from CTE_RN
where RN = 1 or LanguageID = @LanguageID
```

**update**

simplified a bit (join removed), but you'll get the idea:

```
declare @LanguageID int = 2

;with cte_rn as
(
    select
        JobID, LanguageID,
        row_number() over(
          partition by JobTitle.JobID
          order by
              case when LanguageID = @LanguageID then 0 else 1 end, 
              LanguageID
        ) as rn
    from JobTitle
)
select *
from cte_rn
where rn = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/846d1/2)</kbd>**

Comment: +1 i was about to post something similar. No point any more...:)

Comment: yes but by checking LanguageID in where condition returning me 2 rows, where it should return me only 1 row for the passed languageID

Comment: @Rohit see updated, if I understood you right, this is what you need

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT b.[JobID], b.[LanaguageID]
FROM
  (SELECT a.[JobID], a.[LanaguageID],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.[JobID] ORDER BY a.[LanaguageID]) AS [row]
  FROM [JobTitle] a) b
WHERE b.[row] = 1
```

**Result**

```
| JOBID | LANAGUAGEID |
--------|-------------|
|     1 |           1 |
|     2 |           1 |
|     3 |           4 |
|     4 |           5 |
|     5 |           2 |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53dbc/5)

Comment: FreshPrinceOfSO Your query is giving output as desired But I have to pass the languageID and based on that need to generate the output

Comment: @Rohit I think you should be capable of adding a `JOIN` to the query.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, But I didnt get you how join will work in this case ?

Comment: Similarly to query inside the CTE in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987847/679449).

Comment: ok got it. One more thing, if I passed LanguagedID = 2 and for some JobID the record does not exists for that LanguageID. But it present for LanguageID 1(english) and 3(french). Then by default english row should be returned. How can i do this ?